# Excel VBA - Error with sheet selection and check multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

My code stands like this:

```
Sub Tele()

    Dim rowLoop As Long
    rowLoop = 1
    strValueToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter a Search value in format xx.xx.xxxx, remember that this will only work if you are on 'Tidal' tab", Title:="DATE FIND", Default:=Format(Date, "Short Date"), Type:=1)
    ' Loop column A to find value, number corrosponds to letter position in alphabet
    For rowLoop = 1 To Rows.Count
        If Sheets("2015").Cells(rowLoop, 1).Value = strValueToFind Then ' If value is in C then do something
            ' start on cell found from date needed - look at copying range on same Column
            ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("C09").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1).Value
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("C10").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 3).Resize(1).Value
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("C11").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 5).Resize(1).Value
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("C12").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 7).Resize(1).Value
            ' Copy cells 1 cell below found value - Montrose?
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("D09").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 2).Resize(1).Value
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("D10").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 4).Resize(1).Value
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("D11").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 6).Resize(1).Value
            Sheets("Vessels").Range("D12").Value = Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 8).Resize(1).Value
            MsgBox ("Found value on col " & rowLoop) '
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rowLoop ' This is row number, do something with this

    ' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
    MsgBox ("Date not found, make sure you have input the date correctly and on the right tab")

End Sub
```

So here we make the user input a date it searches sheet 2015 and copies some cells based off that position.

Problem:
If on a different sheet, macro does some strange things, using the cell position on that particular sheet.
Currently the code can only check one sheet for the date, I need it to check a total of 5 sheets, 2015 to 2020.
I tried seperating by commas on the if statement inside the sheets parenthesis but I suppose it's not that easy.
Any help or clarification on the error would be great, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to be modified in two ways:-

1. Setup a loop for the worksheets from 2015-2020
2. Set explicit references to `Cells` so that they operate on the correct worksheet

You still have a logic problem. The code below will iterate through 5 sheets (or whatever you add to the array), but each one will overwrite the same cells on the `Vessels' worksheet. I doubt this is what you are looking for.

Try this (in concept):-

```
Sub Tele()

    Dim rowLoop As Long
    rowLoop = 1
    strValueToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter a Search value in format xx.xx.xxxx, remember that this will only work if you are on 'Tidal' tab", Title:="DATE FIND", Default:=Format(Date, "Short Date"), Type:=1)

    '*** REFACTOR THIS - change how sheets are selected. You haven't said if other sheets exists
    'Select the sheets to work through
    Sheets(Array("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020")).Select

    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

      Debug.Print "Checking " & ws.Name

      ' Loop column A to find value, number corrosponds to letter position in alphabet
      For rowLoop = 1 To Rows.Count
        If ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Value = strValueToFind Then ' If value is in C then do something
          ' start on cell found from date needed - look at copying range on same Column
          ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'


          '*** CHANGE THE LOGIC HERE SO SUBSEQUENT SHEETS DON'T OVERWRITE THE VALUES IN "Vessels" ***
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C09").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C10").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 3).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C11").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 5).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("C12").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 7).Resize(1).Value
          ' Copy cells 1 cell below found value - Montrose?
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D09").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 2).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D10").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 4).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D11").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 6).Resize(1).Value
          Sheets("Vessels").Range("D12").Value = ws.Cells(rowLoop, 1).Offset(0, 8).Resize(1).Value
          MsgBox ("Found value on col " & rowLoop) '
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Next rowLoop ' This is row number, do something with this

    'Back for next sheet
    Next ws

    ' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
    MsgBox ("Date not found, make sure you have input the date correctly and on the right tab")

End Sub
```